# How to get specific value from nested JSON object?

Tags: java, android

I want to get a specific value from my nested JSON object like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
         ...
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "nama": "Ngagoes Ulin Kalembur",
            "harga": 250000,
            "deskripsi": "Menikmati serunya berwisata keliling desa-desa di sekitaran desa alamendah menggunakan sepeda, menyusuri pemukiman, kebun-kebun dan pemandangan anda akan menemukan hal menarik selama perjalanan di desa alamendah, Pengemasan sayuran, pengrajin sovenir dll.",
            "gambarid": 11,
            "paketan": true,
            "fasilitas": "Sepeda,Angkutan Umum,Wisata Perternakan,Wisata Kuliner,Wisata Pertanian,Snack,Pemandu Lokal,Air Mineral",
            "totalTiket": 100,
            "minTiket": 50,
            "createdAt": "2021-03-07T10:44:10.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-04-28T13:07:05.000Z",
            "deletedAt": null,
            "gambarId": 11,
            "Gambar": {
                "id": 11,
                "url": "https://desaalamendah.id/images/upload/ImageWisata-1615114030139.png",
                "isGallery": null,
                "createdAt": "2021-03-07T10:44:10.000Z",
                "updatedAt": "2021-03-07T10:47:10.000Z",
                "deletedAt": null
            }
        },
```

I already try `for()` and `if()` condition like this:

```
@override
public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response)
{
    JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
    wisataList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getData()));

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int id = intent.getIntExtra(HomeActivity.EXTRA_NUMBER, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i<jsonResponse.getData().length; i++)
    {
       if (id == i)
       {
         PutDataIntoRecyclerView(wisataList);
       }
    }
}
```

When I run it, it keeps returning all of the values. How to get a specific value, for example `id = 3`, from my nested JSON object?

Comment: add line "wisataList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getData().getJSONObject(i)));" in your if condition inside for loop and remove before loop. So you will get only that data which match condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the following class: `JSONResponse`

Not sure if you were using a library, or has a POJOs called `JSONResponse`

Also, you're calling the `JSONResponse#getData`, it means there's a getter called `getData`

presumably, your project already has a POJO for the attributes inside `"data": [ { ... }, { ... } ]` objects

E.g:

```java
public class JSONResponse {
   private List<Data> data;
   private String success;

   // getter & setter omitted
}
```

```java
public class Data {

   private Integer id;
   private String nama;
   private Integer harga;
   private String deskripsi;
   private Integer gambarid;
   private Boolean paketan;
   private String fasilitas;
   private Integer totalTiket;
   private Integer minTiket;
   private String createdAt;
   private String updatedAt;
   private Object deletedAt;
   private Integer gambarId;
   private Gambar gambar;

   // getter and setter omitted

}
```

```java
public class Gambar {

   private Integer id;
   private String url;
   private Object isGallery;
   private String createdAt;
   private String updatedAt;
   private Object deletedAt;

   // getter and setter omitted

}
```

> Generate POJOs from JSON: https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
>
> Or you can use plugins: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8533-json2pojo

Here's the alternative approach might works for your usecases:

```java
@override
public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response)
{
    JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
    wisataList = new ArrayList<Data>();

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int id = intent.getIntExtra(HomeActivity.EXTRA_NUMBER, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i<jsonResponse.getData().length; i++)
    {
        Data wisata = jsonResponse.getData().get(i);
        if (id == wisata.getId())
        {
            wisatList.add(wisata);
            // break; // optional if you want to stop iterating, if the wisata already found
        }
    }
    PutDataIntoRecyclerView(wisataList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [org.json.simple](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonsimple11jar.htm) library. You would do it like this:

```
import org.json.simple.*;

// I imagine response.body() is a String, if not, convert it to String
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(response.body());
JSONArray data = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("data");

for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject2 = (JSONObject)data.get(i);
    String id = (String) jsonObject2.get("id");
    
    if((id != null) && (id.equals("3"))){
        String nama_ = (String) jsonObject3.get("nama");
        //...
    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But.. where are you assigning the json data into?
to simplify it - a small example - hope this helps

**dataset:**

```
let jsonData = {
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "test",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "test2",
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "test3",
        }
    ]
};
```

**Get id=='2':**

```
let response = jsonData.data.find(ele => ele.id == '2');
```

**Response now has value of:**

```
{ "id": 2, "name": "test2" }
```